# Proving the associativity of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, here's what I'm trying to prove right now.

Let $A \in M(m \times n, F)$, $B \in M(n \times s,F)$ and $C \in M(s \times p,F)$. Then:

$$A(BC) = (AB)C$$

---

Proof Attempt:

The linear maps corresponding to each of the matrices above are denoted as follows:

$$f:F^n \to F^m$$

$$g:F^s \to F^n$$

$$h:F^p \to F^s$$

Now, consider the following:

$[f \circ (g \circ h)](x) = f((g \circ h)(x) = f(g(h(x))) = (f \circ g)(h(x)) = [(f \circ g) \circ h](x)$

In other words, compositions of functions is associative. Since the matrix product corresponds to the composition of two linear maps, it follows that the above corresponds to the following law:

$$A(BC) = (AB)C$$

That proves the desired result.

I know how to prove the given result directly from the definition of matrix multiplication. However, my book seems to be focusing quite a lot on the relationship between function composition and matrix multiplication. In all honesty, that makes more sense in my mind so I'm trying to do the proofs of these laws with reference to that. Can someone have a look at what I've written above and see if it is correct or not? How could I improve the proof?

Comment: The proof is fine, and in fact I think it is better than trying to multiply all the matrices out (but of course, you should do such tedious computations atleast once in your life). One comment I have is the following: you claim that "since matrix product corresponds to the composition..." This is of course right, but do you know/are you able to rigorously and explicitly state what the "correspondence" is? If yes, then this proof is complete, and you did a good job.

Comment: Ughh i hate doing such computations, I just mess them up. Also, that correspondence is described by the bijective linear map $f:M(m \times n,F) \to Hom(F^n,F^m)$. The proof for that is something I'm still trying to iron out, actually. I've just moved on because I don't want to get stuck on that entirely.

Comment: I hate them too, but some things just have to be learned and practiced by brute force... good luck with that. Actually, the bijective linear map $f$ is only half the story, because a bijection between those two spaces only tells you that for each matrix there is a unique linear map, and vice-versa, but the bijection makes no reference to how matrix product is related to function composition. I'll try to elaborate more in an answer

Comment: Hmmm yea, I'd like to see your take on this. My textbook has done a good job of explaining the motivation for defining the matrix product by considering the image of the jth unit vector in $F^n$ but it's a rather terse book so I'm kind of still wrapping my mind around it. I'm glad someone agrees that matrix multiplication crap is just painful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you are aware of the linear bijection between the space of matrices, and the space of linear maps; let me be more explicit. Let $m,n,p$ be positive integers. We can define a function $\alpha: M_{m \times n}(F) \to \text{Hom}(F^n, F^m)$ by the rule: for any $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$, we define $\alpha(A): F^n \to F^m$ to be the function defined by
\begin{align}
\left(\alpha(A) \right)(x) &:= A \cdot x \qquad \text{for all $x \in F^n$.} \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

Now, you should verify that this function $\alpha$ is really a bijection between those spaces, and that it is linear (if you've gotten stuck, then maybe you should move on temporarily, but definitely be sure to come back to this and prove it rigorously). We can of course define a similar maps $\beta: M_{n \times p}(F) \to \text{Hom}(F^p, F^n)$ and $\xi: M_{m \times p}(F) \to \text{Hom}(F^p, F^m)$.

Now, the statement that "matrix product corresponds to function composition" means that the function $\xi$ has the following property: for all $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$ and all $B \in M_{n \times p}(F)$,
\begin{align}
\xi(A \cdot B) &= \alpha(A) \circ \beta(B). \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}
\end{align}

The way to read this equation in words is"the linear map associated with the product $A \cdot B$ equals the composition of the linear map associated with $A$ and the linear map associated with $B$" (verify using the definition that $\xi$ really does have this property).

---

Up until now, I have intentionally introduced new letters $\alpha, \beta, \xi$ to emphasize that these are all different functions with different domains and target spaces. However, usually what happens is people may write $\alpha(A)$ simply as $L_A$, to mean "left-multiplication by $A$", and similarly write $L_B$ to mean "left-multiplication by $B$" instead of $\beta(B)$. The reason for such language is evident from ($*$), because the value of the function $L_A$ on the vector $x$ is simply obtained by multiplying the vector $x$ on the left by the matrix $A$.

With such notation, the equation $(\ddot{\smile})$ may be written in a more memorable manner:
\begin{align}
L_{A \cdot B} &= L_A \circ L_B
\end{align}

This should make it more apparent that matrix product "really corresponds to" function composition (of the associated linear maps).

I hope you appreciate that this notation of left-multiplication is really much more convenient than the notation $\alpha, \beta, \xi$, which I have introduced so far (but of course, one needs to implicitly keep track of which $L$ refers to which).

One other thing to mention is that bijectivity of $\alpha$ in particular means it is injective so that if $\alpha(A_1) = \alpha(A_2)$ then $A_1 = A_2$. Or, if we use the $L$ notation, this is the same as saying if $L_{A_1} = L_{A_2}$ then $A_1 = A_2$. Similar statements hold for $\beta, \xi$. Now, the proof of matrix multiplication associativity becomes almost trivial, like you said
\begin{align}
L_{(AB)C} &= L_{AB} \circ L_C\\
& = \left(L_A \circ L_B\right) \circ L_C \\
&= L_A \circ \left(L_B \circ L_C \right) \\
&= L_A \circ L_{BC} \\
&= L_{A(BC)}.
\end{align}

Hence, by my remark about injectivity earlier, this implies $(AB)C = A(BC)$.

---

**Final Words:**

- You seemed to grasp the main idea of the proof. All I did was try to make super explicit what the "correspondence" between matrix multiplication and function composition is, so that the logic of the proof is airtight.
- Note that while the actual proof of associativity above is definitely shorter than the proof using explicit matrix multiplication, this proof requires some "background machinery"; and there were several details which I left for you to verify. So, this isn't necessarily a "quicker" proof. However, it is definitely more conceptually clear, and it is worth learning, because once you understand the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations, proving new/ more complicated theorems about matrices could then become a very quick proof if you rephrase it using linear maps (and sometimes, proving facts about linear maps becomes much more obvious once you consider the associated matrix).

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights, I'm literally just going to take down what you've just said cos I think it'll be good to include it in my notes. I'm still kind of working on making my proofs entirely airtight so I'm gonna need way more practise with that, it seems.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats by the way, out of curiosity, which textbook are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linear Algebra by Klaus Janich. He's not your typical author who does the standard definition-theorem approach thing. There are proofs but, for the most part, it's me trying to prove any kind of assertion he's making. I quite like that style, to be honest. It fits really well with my style, especially since I'm self-studying.